# Why does `EffectScope.shift` need the type parameter `B`?

Tags: kotlin, generics, arrow-kt

The move to the new continuations API in Arrow brought with it a handy new function: `shift`, in theory letting me get rid of `ensure(false) { NewError() }` or `NewError().left().bind()` constructs.

But I'm not sure how to properly use it. The documentation states that it is intended to short-circuit the continuation, and there are no conditionals, so it should always take the parameter, and (in either parlance) "make it a left value", and exit the scope.

So what is the type parameter `B` intended to be used for? It determines the return type of `shift`, but `shift` will not return. Given no more context, `B` can not be inferred, leading to this kind of code:

```kotlin
val res = either {
  val intermediate = mayReturnNull()
  if (intermediate == null) {
    shift<Nothing>(IntermediateWasNull())
  }
  process(intermediate)
}
```

Note the `<Nothing>` (and ignore the contrived example, the main point is that `shift`s return type can not be inferred – the actual type parameter does not even matter).

I could wrap `shift` like this:

```kotlin
suspend fun <L> EffectScope<L>.fail(left: L): Nothing = shift(left)
```

But I feel like that is missing the point. Any explanations/hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a great question!

This is more a matter of style, ideally we'd have both but they conflict so we cannot have both APIs available.

So `shift` always returns `Nothing` in its implementation, and so the `B` parameter is completely artificial.

This is something that is true for a lot of other things in Kotlin, such as `object EmptyList : List<Nothing>`. The Kotlin Std however exposes it as `fun <A> emptyList(): List<A> = EmptyList`.

For Arrow to stay consistent with APIs found in Kotlin Std, and to remain as Kotlin idiomatic as possible we also require a type argument just like `emptyList`. This has been up for discussion multiple times, and the Kotlin languages authors have stated that it was decided too explicitly require `A` for `emptyList` since that results in the best and most consistent ergonomics in Kotlin.

In the example you shared I would however recommend using `ensureNotNull` which will also smart-cast `intermediate` to `non-null`.
Arrow attempts to build the DSL so that you don't need to rely on `shift` in most cases, and you should prefer `ensure` and `ensureNotNull` when possible.

```kotlin
val res = either {
  val intermediate = mayReturnNull()
  ensureNotNull(intermediate) { IntermediateWasNull() }
  process(intermediate) // <-- smart casted to non-null
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer! Every open source project should have a lead dev watching the SO tags related to the project ;-) To the topic: so I gather that I am not completely wrong with my implementation of `fail`. That is what I needed to know. I considered using `ensure(NotNull)`, but I need to cause some side effects as well, and it did not feel right to put those calls into the `ensure` block parameters. A lowly `if` and a "`returnLeft`"-like function fit my situation better. So, thanks again!